# pop method LinkedList Class

Tags: python, linked-list, nodes

I have implemented the `LinkedList` class: I need to implement the `pop()` which takes no parameter. The method removes and returns the item at the end of the linked list. If the list is empty it returns `None` and does nothing.

```
class LinkedList:
        def __init__(self):
            self.head = None
            self.count = 0
    
        def is_empty(self):
            return self.count == 0
    
        def size(self):
            return self.count
    
        def add(self, item):
            new_node = Node(item)
            new_node.set_next(self.head)
            self.head = new_node
            self.count += 1
    
        def search(self, item):
            current = self.head 
            while current != None:
                if current.get_data() == item:
                    return True
                else:
                    current = current.get_next()
            return False
    
        def remove(self, item):
            found = False
            current = self.head
            previous = None
            while current != None and not found:
                if current.get_data() == item:
                    found = True
                else:
                    previous = current
                    current = current.get_next()
            if found:
                if previous == None:
                    self.head = current.get_next()
                else:
                    previous.set_next(current.get_next())
                self.count -= 1
            else:
                raise ValueError("remove(" + str(item) + "). " + str(item) + " is not in list")
                
        def clear(self):
            self.head = None
            self.count = 0
                
        def __str__(self):
            temp = self.head
            if(temp != None):
                output ="Head"
                while (temp != None):
                    output = output+" --> "+str(temp.data)
                    temp = temp.next
                return output
            else:
                return "Head --> None"
                
        def append(self, item):
            new_node = Node(item)
    
            if self.head is None:
                self.head = new_node
                return
            last = self.head
            while(last.next):
                last = last.next
    
            last.next = new_node
            
        def pop(self):   #Problem here
            if self.head is None:
                return None
            else:
                popnode = self.head
                self.head = self.head.next
                popnode.next = None
                return popnode.data
```

Test:

```
a_list = LinkedList()
a_list.add(1)
a_list.add(2)
a_list.add(3)
print(a_list)
print("Removed item:",a_list.pop())
print("Removed item:",a_list.pop())
print(a_list)
```

Expected Output:

```
Head --> 3 --> 2 --> 1
Removed item: 1
Removed item: 2
Head --> 3
```

Recd Output:

```
Head --> 3 --> 2 --> 1
Removed item: 3
Removed item: 2
Head --> 1
```

Test:

```
a_list = LinkedList()
a_list.append(1)
a_list.append(2)
a_list.append(3)
print(a_list)
print("Removed item:",a_list.pop())
print("Removed item:",a_list.pop())
print(a_list)
```

Expected output:

```
Head --> 1 --> 2 --> 3
Removed item: 3
Removed item: 2
Head --> 1
```

Recd output:

```
Head --> 1 --> 2 --> 3
Removed item: 1
Removed item: 2
Head --> 3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simplified `pop()` method which does what you require -

```
def pop(self):   #Problem here
    # Empty LinkedList
    if self.head is None:
        return None

    # There is a single node in the LinkedList = head, read data and delete it
    if self.head.next is None:
        data = self.head.data
        self.head = None
        return data
    
    # there are 2 or more nodes in the LinkedList
    secondlast = self.head
    while (secondlast.next.next):
        secondlast = secondlast.next
    # found the second last node
    # read the data of the last node and then delete it, by setting secondlast.next = None
    data = secondlast.next.data
    secondlast.next = None
    return data
```

another approach using a temporary dummy node to simplify case when there is a single node in the `LinkedList`-

```
def pop(self):   #Problem here
    # Empty linkedlist
    if self.head is None:
        return None
    # create a dummy secondlast node
    secondlast = Node(-1)
    secondlast.next = self.head
    while (secondlast.next.next):
        secondlast = secondlast.next
    data = secondlast.next.data
    secondlast.next = None
    return data
```

In your `LinkedList`, both `append()` and `pop()` methods are `O(n)`, since you need to traverse through whole `LinkedList` to do those operations. Consider adding a new property `self.tail`(or `self.secondlast`) to the `LinkedList` which keeps track of the last node in the LinkedList. It would help in simplifying the code and making both `append()` and `pop()` operations `O(1)`

Answer (score 1):

Just track `popnode.next` when become `None` and at the same time store previous item, when `popnode.next` become None, Just put next of prev None, and return data of `popnode.next`:

```python
def pop(self):  # Problem here
    if self.head is None:
        return None
    elif self.head.next == None:
        d = self.head.data
        self.head = None
        return d
    else:
        popnode = self.head
        prev = popnode
        while popnode.next:
            prev = popnode
            popnode = popnode.next
        prev.next = None
        return popnode.data
```

The output of:

```python
a_list = LinkedList()
a_list.add(1)
a_list.add(2)
a_list.add(3)
print(a_list)
print("Removed item:", a_list.pop())
print("Removed item:", a_list.pop())
print("Removed item:", a_list.pop())
print(a_list)
```

Will be:

```python
Head --> 3--> 2--> 1
Removed item: 1
Removed item: 2
Removed item: 3
Head  None
```

Comment: This will not work when there is only 1 node in the `LinkedList`

Comment: I added example, When there is 3 node

Comment: Try doing `pop()` once again in your example, the `a_list` would still remain as `Head --> 3` instead of it being empty.